# Latin Proverb Translation

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

How would I translate this Latin proverb:

"Qui se instar ovis gerit hunc lupi vorant."

Here's what I have:

"Those who devour themselves like a sheep carries this man of a wolf."

Comment: You're just throwing words at it without considering case or number. There's only one word in the nominative plural that can serve as the subject of *vorant*, and while *ovis* formally looks like a nominative, that's in fact not all it can be.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Give MichaelJYoo some credit. He's seeing *qui...vorant*, which isn't entirely unreasonable, as *qui* could be plural.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Not a fair assessment, Michael correctly understood the *instar* + genetive construction, and *qui* could theoretically be nominative plural too.

Answer (score 7):

The chief problem with the current offering is that the word order does matter, that if you have a relative clause, the main verb shouldn't go between the relative pronoun and the verb in the relative clause.

So you have relative clause first: {{*qui se instar ovis gerit*}} *hunc lupi vorant.* In English word order, we would typically put the main clause first or otherwise keep it as the subject of both, but the word order here.

> Wolves eat him who carries himself like a sheep.

If you wanted to keep the word order, you could make it the passive subject of the main clause and turn the nominative *lupi* into an agent:

> He who carries himself like a sheep is eaten by wolves.

Just a note on *se gerere*, like English "to carry oneself" has the sense of "to conduct oneself in a certain way/to act in a certain way", so the meaning, while clear in the above translations, can be distilled even further into a more popular format:

> If you act like a sheep, you get eaten by wolves.

Comment: I feel somewhat different sense of the sentence. something like: "It is him - who act(s) like a sheep, that wolves eat". it is very close indeed, but here the subject is the person and not the wolves. This reading may be supported by the the indicative *gerit* ( see also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547652/i-am-the-man-who-commands-you-vs-i-am-the-man-who-command-you) ; and my answer to that question )